# Android: How to make TextView's shadow apply to its CompoundDrawable

Tags: android, textview

I'm using a `TextView` with a compound drawable, and adding a shadow to the TextView by using`android:shadowColor`, but the result is:

[image]

As shown in the picture, text of the `TextView` has the shadow(glow effect) while the drawable doesn't.

So what can I do with this? Or is there any other way to implement this effect? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, may it help you

```
   <TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="12dp"
android:text="@string/glow"
android:textSize="80sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:shadowColor="@color/yellow"
android:shadowDx="0"
android:shadowDy="0"
android:shadowRadius="24"/>
```

or you can reffere below link,

http://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview/#/

Comment: It's almost the same code with what i'm using, I want the drawable has the glow effect. Not work, but Thx all the same.